90s UK kids show - possibly time travel related
I'm trying to find out the name of a kids show I used to watch in the 90s. Probably on the BBC.
I don't remember much but I remember a kid somehow went back in time, to a land which is ruled by people with technologically advanced 'suits' with some kind of energy weapon built into the front. This guy then proceeds to try to help the common folk who are being oppressed.
I remember him have a portable TV with him, and he makes a friend who is fascinated by it and is asking why people are in the TV.
This kid somehow get hold of one of the suits at some point but I remember he doesn't have any energy to power it. Maybe he powers it later but I can't remember.

Was this animated or live-action?

Are you sure they went "back" in time? The mention of technologically advanced suits doesn't seem to tie in with that?

No it wasn't animated, they used actors

And I'm pretty sure he went back in time because people had swords and wore chainmail etc, but he had his portable tv and Walkman with him. I remember he befriended a 'native' and she was amazed by the technology

And the suits didn't look particularly advanced, they were just these metal vests they strapped to themselves. But they fired out these balls of 'energy' so much more powerful that a sword

@Dom It would be helpful to edit these additional details into your question.

It reminds me of Spellbinder, and Australian TV show that was aired on The Disney Channel in the US alongside Ocean Girl.  It wasn't time travel though, but he traveled through a dimensional portal.  I do remember he had a Walkman with him, and there are powered suits that those in power used to control people, as well as flying ships that utilized the same power.  I don't remember the portable TV, but I do remember they figured out how to travel back and forth through the gate and he brought people from the other dimension to his.




I think that might be it. The storey sounds very similar although I don't remember the Australian accents lol. Wiki says it aired on ITV so that must have been when I saw it. Thanks!

It looks like the entire series is currently available on youtube, I think I'll be binge watching it shortly, it's been 20 years since I saw it!  Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer :-) https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQIcUY6Kr8n5OEi1GFHYQ9Lf7L6t3FRYL
